# Wordpress Install step 2 page blank

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, ibm-cloud

Everytime I run a new wordpress 4.1.1 install the first install page works fine: i.stack.imgur.com/31mzE.png

but once I hit "Install WordPress" the next page (myWordpressSite.net/wp-admin/install.php?step=2) shows up like this: i.stack.imgur.com/glAUS.png

If I refresh the page I get this: [image]

After that everything works perfect. I'm just wondering If anyone has seen this behavior before, could this be a sign of underlying problems in in my install? Also I am installing wordpress core using composer with this [installer](https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer).

Comment: Have you already installed WP? Maybe the database table schema exists already?

Comment: nope, got a new database instance running

Comment: Did you use the wordpress boilerplate in bluemix or https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress-core-installer

Comment: I used the boilerplate. The boilerplate uses the johnpbloch installer to install wordpress. So I technically used both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deployed the boilerplate and I got to the same place.  It looks like Wordpress is not redirecting to login after the setup completes.  If you click "Log In" and login with the username and password you just created it works.

Comment: Yep, refreshing the page gets things working again, but I just don't like that users will see a half loaded page during the first steps of the wordpress deploy. I'm one of the developers on the boilerplate.

Comment: Lee has opened an internal ticket to work on this.  Wanna accept the answer for now and then work with Lee to resolve it?

Comment: if anyone encounters simillar issues: it looks like it might be a database issue, turning on WP_DEBUG in wp-config reveals the following issue.    WordPress database error: [Table 'ad_7128b7d9d49a437.bluemix_0_5_wp_options' doesn't exist]
INSERT INTO `bluemix_0_5_wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('default_plugins_activated', '1', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

Comment: Looks like wordpress is attempting to modify tables before the installer creates them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the php_mysqli extension is enable in php.ini